# auto refresh div / or remove the style using only javascrpit

Tags: javascript

a lot of similar questions have already been answered but nothing seems to work for me, so I want to highlight the element on click of the navigation bar(8k), and then remove it after a few seconds, I just can't figure out how to do it without refreshing the whole page. Is there any way to refresh the div only and or it can be done without refresh? (beginner here).  **Thanks**

**Javascript**

```
function dance() {
  document.getElementById("c4").style.boxShadow= "0 4px 8px 0 rgba(218, 51, 119, 0.4), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="../pics/-vine-3404474.jpg" id="c4">

<div class="flex-nav" id="n1">
<a href="#" style="order:3">2k</a>
<a href="#" style="order:2">4k</a>
<a href="#" style="order:4">1080p</a>
<a href="#C2" style="order:1" onclick="dance()">8k</a>
</div>
```

Comment: so you have a `highlight` css class that you want to apply on a `div` when you click it,  you then you automotically remove that style after some seconds?

Comment: Create a class with the style in CSS and then add the class and finally use settimeout to remove the class?

Comment: no, I haven't created a separate class, but when someone clicks on the navigation bar(8k) it will call the function (dance) that will apply box-shadow to the element which will eventually highlight the div. the trouble I'm having is I want to remove the highlight(box-shadow) after some seconds, without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: First of, stop using inline `on*` attribute handlers (*onclick* etc). JS should be in one place only and that's the respective tag of file. Use `Element.addEventListener()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Per comments, I've added a `clearTimeout` call and replaced the inline `onclick` handler with a generic `addEventListener` call as a recommendation.

As an additional suggestion, I'd also recommend that you replace `<div class="flex-nav">` with a `<nav>` tag and potentially `<a>` with `<button>` for semantic markup.

---

Added a few lines of CSS and one additional line of JavaScript.

On click, add a `.highlight` class with a `setTimeout` call to remove it after a given time.

```js
const image = document.getElementById("c4");
let timeoutID;
document.querySelectorAll(".flex-nav a").forEach(item => item.addEventListener("click", dance));

function dance() {
  image.classList.add('highlight');
  timeoutID = setTimeout(() => { 
    image.classList.remove('highlight');
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  }, 1000)
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(218, 51, 119, 0.4), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  animation: dance infinite linear 0.5s;
}

@keyframes dance {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/400/100" id="c4">

<div class="flex-nav" id="n1">
<a href="#" style="order:3">2k</a>
<a href="#" style="order:2">4k</a>
<a href="#" style="order:4">1080p</a>
<a href="#C2" style="order:1">8k</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `const timeout` makes no sense. And you're also running into the trouble of stacking multiple timeouts on repeated click. Also, stop using inline **unsafe** `on*` handlers.

Comment: @BumhanYu I like your answer and the effect! +1up

Comment: Your edit is not complete. You still need to clear ongoing timeouts using `clearTimeout`. You can olways use a custom property attaching it to the Element itself like: `clearTimeout(image._tOut)` and than use `image._tOut = setTimeout(`

Comment: Also your example condemns itself to one element only. Programming is not about repeating functions, but to reuse them passing arguments and returning an output that depends on the arguments input.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks for hint. I updated my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71328670/14807111 .

Comment: For some reason, this is working perfectly here and on codepen too, but nothing happens when I'm running it through vs code. Do you have any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: @coddein Note that I removed your inline `onclick` handler from `a` tag, and replaced with a more generic `addEventListener`.

Comment: @BumhanYu i replaced ( flex-nav with side-nav) as there is already a class with nav and also changed <a> with button tag, changed inline ``onclick`` and replaced with ``addEventListener`` as you told me to. And this is working perfectly fine on codepen but for some reason nothing is happening on offline local server. Do you have any idea why this could be?

Comment: @BumhanYu here is the codepen (https://codepen.io/xivox/pen/YzEdMVQ)

Comment: There might be a JavaScript error in the browser console. Please see if there's anything, and go from there.

Comment: @BumhanYu I Fixed that issue, I have one more issue please if you can help I want the highlight to happen only when I click on 8k, not on the other buttons.

Comment: You'd need to tweak `querySelectorAll` part to fit your needs, so that it only targets your specific element. Or, for a quick solution, you can add back your `onclick` on your element.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** Based on your code, I have added two functions. The first function is about the timer and removing the element. the second function is the timer itself.

```js
function dance() {
 const el = document.getElementById("c4");
 el.style.boxShadow = "0 4px 8px 0 rgba(218, 51, 119, 0.4), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)";
  
  start(el);
} 


function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function start(el) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(`Waiting ${i} seconds...`);
    await sleep(i * 1000);
  }
  console.log('Done');
  el.style.boxShadow = null;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" id="c4">

<div class="flex-nav" id="n1">
<a href="#" style="order:3">2k</a>
<a href="#" style="order:2">4k</a>
<a href="#" style="order:4">1080p</a>
<a href="#C2" style="order:1" onclick="dance()">8k</a>
</div>
```

Comment: OP said he only want the highlight to **disappear** not the `div`. he mentioned that in a comment.

Comment: Ok. I guess I missed the comment or it wasn't there when I wrote the answer. but there is already a solution. Thank you @medilies for your positive feedback and support! good karma

Answer (score 0):

```js
let hide;
function highlight(){
  clearTimeout(hide);
  document.getElementById("highlight").classList.add("highlight");
  hide= setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("highlight").classList.toggle("highlight"), 3000);
}
```

```css
.highlight{
box-shadow: 1px 5px 6px 3px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="highlight" onclick="highlight()"> Hello, I am a beginner in web dev.</div>
```

Comment: And a bad solution is here. By clicking multiple times, you will stack timeouts.

Comment: This is something I tried to do but I wasn't able to access and apply the class to the element. Thank you so much for helping me, the problem is solved now.

Comment: Also, `onclick` is something we should leave to w3schools. Please use addEventListener. Please get fluid with JS.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljanwill you please explain this with an example. and why should we not use onclick?

Comment: @coddein read the comment under OP's Question.

Comment: @Roko That is exactly what I thought. The problem is that setTimeout is being stacked on top of each other. Not the ideal way of doing this.

Comment: @coddein There are various reasons of why one shouldn't use onclick but the most important one is that addEventListener makes it easier to handle the code. Rather than using onclicks you can use a single addeventlistener otherwise your whole HTML will be just onclicks and it will become redundant.

Comment: @AliMustafa first of, `on*` handlers are unsafe. 2. the code becomes hard to debug. 3. onclick should **only be only used** when creating brand new Elements from in-memory and than appended to the DOM. Everything else should be *additions*, not *overrides*. Therefore addEventListener() and JS held up in one place, not dispersed around your HTML markup.